# Remove last two characters from each database value

Tags: sql, oracle

I run the following query:

```
select * from my_temp_table
```

And get this output:

> PNRP1-109/RT
>   PNRP1-200-16
>   PNRP1-209/PG
>   013555366-IT

How can I alter my query to strip the last two characters from each value?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SUBSTR()` function.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(my_column, 1, LENGTH(my_column) - 2) FROM my_table;
```

Comment: @Troll: not the downvoter (frankly it's the answer I was going to post :-) but: you might want to consider what will happen if one of the strings is less than 3 characters long, and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace('PNRP1-109/RT', '^(.*).{2}$', '\1') from dual;
```

This replaces your string with group 1 from the regular expression, where group 1 (inside of the parens) includes the set of characters after the beginning of the line, not including the 2 characters just before the end of the line.

While not as simple for your example, arguably more powerful.